# How to change the scientific scale value in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying create a simple plot with matplotlib but I couldn't change to scientific notation from 1e7 to 1e6 for the purpose to visualize the y axis as millions.

[image]

I tried plt.ticklabel_format(scilimits=(x,y)) but it did only disabled the scaling.

Comment: Try with `scilimits=(6,6)`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77847279/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @antaz Oh thanks I was using the wrong combinations.